# Open WiFi Network Where All Confidential Communication is Encrypted Through Other Means

Tags: wifi

Imagine the following scenario:

- Users connect to an open WiFi network (no password, no encryption)
- All users stick to secure transmission protocols for all confidential data (HTTPS, SSH, VPN, etc.)
- Users devices do not accept any inbound connections

Would this scenario provide a reasonable level of security for the users involved? Or perhaps more importantly, does a malicious user's presence on an unencrypted WiFi network pose a known threat to the other users?

Comment: Secure from what? Even though the content is encrypted, other data is available (destination, presence of the client, active use, etc.) What's your threat concern?

Comment: You also have the obvious MITM issues to deal with, but I'm not sure that is in scope of your question.

Comment: @schroeder I assume by MITM you mean relating to trusting the router/network itself? I more mean only the other users being untrusted. And I largely mean from an anonymity/confidentiality perspective. I'm not sure client existence or destination IPs are going to tell other users much?

Comment: MITM means a malicious actor on the open network forcing traffic through their computer in order to collect content of encrypted streams. Destination IPs are not the only destination data: DNS queries and domain names can also be sent in the clear even when using encrypted communication.

Comment: @schroeder Even still, does that data necessarily pose a threat to that user's identity or data? Except in extreme cases where the malicious user may be able to infer the identity of another with this information, I'm not sure I see how it poses a general threat.

Comment: We're back to "secure from what?" If that kind of data is out of scope for you, then there is no threat for you. But if I want to browse sites and not have anyone know what sites I'm hitting (silk road, child porn, bomb making sites, etc.) then even DNS queries are a threat to my anonymity/confidentiality.

Comment: @schroeder Ah, okay. I suppose that makes enough sense. No need to create a reason for people to target you. That does provide an interestingly limited use-case for encrypted WiFi, though, since I would imagine the majority of people would only care about this for mild embarrassment reasons (regular pornography, my little pony fan websites, etc.). Still, for full/true confidentially some form of encryption on this level is probably worthwhile. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yep, look into ARP poisoning.  A malicious user could trivially redirect the legitimate users' traffic.